# Getting an error while passing props to child in react TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, parent-child

I am new to React and Typescript. When I am trying to pass props to child from parent I am getting Error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ changeValue: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'changeValue' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

parent.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Child } from '../components/Child';

const Parent: React.FC = () => {

    function changeValue() {
        console.log("hello");
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <Child changeValue={changeValue}/>
      </div>
  );
};
export default Parent;
```

Child.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

export const Child: React.FC = (props) => {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState(
    'let name; \n' + 'let age; \n' + 'name = 5;'
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        id="details"
        name="details"
        value={props.data}
        onChange={() => changeValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I saw some answers in stackoverflow, but not able to figure out why the error is coming. I am not sure what I am missing here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to invoke the function with parentheses in your Child component: `onChange={() => props.changeValue()}`

Comment: After adding that also I am getting error: TS2339: Property 'changeValue' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.

Comment: Maybe it's better to take a step back before going forward: What exactly do you want your Child component to do (how do you want it to behave)? (Same question for the parent.) Add this goal to your question so we can know how to help you get the correct types for your components.

Comment: When there is some change in the child textarea, I want to update something in the parent. That's why I am trying to pass a method of parent and will execute on onChange of child.

Comment: Another thing, Is it possible to pass parent function to child and execute on changes in a child?

Comment: Yes, I'll write up an example in an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a functional example of [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in TypeScript React using a [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) `textarea` element:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=2&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMAiB5AsnAMyghDgHIpUMBaAExLIG4BYAKFEljgG8245aSAigCuAG3goAzoiowANH1noYAUTFIQSAHYKlIqUgDKMFDCSLWAX0LFSFOUzZsYATzBI4AYQAWwMbQACsRgMgC8PEo+KNq0Gr4xAOZIAFxwABQAbihiIqlwUjBQwNqJAJRwYQB8cJkQwLQsrPzmAB4waYXFpU1WTWxoENqF3n4BlRlgIVJpvv5B02VpyCrqmjrw1ZHNcJQwIlDaGUr8ADy0wJlVJ-xwp22mlCg3t3ANYQBEgqb+Uh8vt20KC0n2+KF+-x2r34QwSpSQYW4SEylRqUwgoQAdNFYvEccl0sjMY9kjBMdlckgylYAfwKXlEeisQ8aVDbgB6a5s07si5XJRlXr9ViDYbwQIoSi6CbpJbKDBrLTSra8HaikYAbQeADUcnl5AUkDAACpIdq6ykAXQmBmMpnM6TIGngQK0jDgAB1tGQ4ABqcjOuAoZLur0+-1kV2eCIAVkYZEFzjVQxGOLiSFN5r1SDhyRl9PyXRK5VR21e6ogGkxYggiSy2cTbMMJrNMAteXrlMb-D6Sf4ewOR3SN3Oly50Luc3GD0ROuzNjTeKSCO4i4zrfbOfxSBsnJHvLHAqFSYIIm0GGAQzgqlawLAGgycpWCo0Svgqv7RsHdwlUvgnN6JNnywPBMSlQQoHSU4bzvB9OQNeg0BEN9MVJRUNgAIVcABJWhHWICAYATRsgA)

```ts
import {
  default as React,
  ReactElement,
  useState,
} from 'react';

type ChildProps = {
  handleChange: (value: string) => void;
  text: string;
};

const Child = (props: ChildProps): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        id="details"
        name="details"
        onChange={ev => props.handleChange(ev.target.value)}
        value={props.text}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = (): ReactElement => {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState('let name; \n' + 'let age; \n' + 'name = 5;');

  const handleTextValueChange = (value: string) => {
    console.log(value);
    setTextValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Child text={textValue} handleChange={handleTextValueChange} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can run the example above using this snippet code to see it working:

```css
textarea {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 70vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.4/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

/**
 * The following line is here because this Stack Overflow snippet uses the
 * UMD module for React. In your code, you'd use the commented `import` lines
 * below it.
 */
const {useState} = React;

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import {
//   default as React,
//   ReactElement,
//   useState,
// } from 'react';

type ChildProps = {
  handleChange: (value: string) => void;
  text: string;
};

const Child = (props: ChildProps): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        id="details"
        name="details"
        onChange={ev => props.handleChange(ev.target.value)}
        value={props.text}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = (): ReactElement => {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState('let name; \n' + 'let age; \n' + 'name = 5;');

  const handleTextValueChange = (value: string) => {
    console.log(value);
    setTextValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Child text={textValue} handleChange={handleTextValueChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

function Example (): ReactElement {
  return <Parent />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I missed adding ChildProps property. It's working now.

Comment: @lakshmiravalirimmalapudi There's a lot of (bad) advice on the internet about using `React.FC`. Don't use it, and instead: type your React functions like normal TS functions. If they return a React element, use `ReactElement` as the return type.

Comment: Okay, but when I want to use some functions of child component in parent Is it works?

Comment: @lakshmiravalirimmalapudi I'm not sure that I understand your question. If you mean, "Is typing components the way I described in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70255498/getting-an-error-while-passing-props-to-child-in-react-ts/70255753?noredirect=1#comment124192950_70255753) going to work for the compiler and your runtime code?", then the answer is yes.

Comment: My question is If there is a method in Childs component and I want to invoke it from Parent Component. Is it possible?

Comment: @lakshmiravalirimmalapudi It's more idiomatic to create the function in the parent component and then pass it down to the child. That's what I illustrated in my answer.